# Can't Write "<" or ">"

Tags: symbols

I can't seem to write this symbol "< >" in Latex.  [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could try adding  `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preamble of your document. Also, you don't have to write "Hello" or "Please help".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you write in Portuguese, you *need*

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and possibly add

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

to your document preamble. The first package is needed in order to make hyphenation of accented words possible also past an accent, which in Portuguese is essential.

With this, an input such as

```
Formato reconhecido <Especificador>
```

will print as expected. However, it's traditional to print such keywords in a monospaced font, in order to make them distinguishable from the context. So

```
Formato reconhecido \texttt{<Especificador>}
```

is my recommendation.

Minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} % or brazil

\begin{document}

Formato reconhecido <Especificador>

Formato reconhecido \texttt{<Especificador>}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Even better: `\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\texttt{#1}}` and `Formato reconhecido \keyword{<Especificador>}`. Just in case you ever decide that you want all keywords typeset in red and italic, instead of monospace.

Comment: @Fritz You're completely right.